# Delaying PHP code for some time when reaching out to a Payment Gateway

Tags: php, laravel, sleep, payment-processing

I am working on a Laravel PHP project whereby I reach out to an Payment API to check the status if the user has paid and redirect the user to a payment-confirm page.

By default the payment status from the Payment gateway is 0. When a user pays the status changes to 1. After user hits payment button on the website, I need to delay the execution of the PHP code (to allow the user some time to transact payment through his/her phone).

After 15 seconds, I reach out to the payment gateway to check if the status has changes to 1, if true redirect the user to payment-confirmation page.

I have tried to use sleep but it isn't working... I have also tested using a sandbox account while paying but it isn't redirecting as expected after the 15 seconds.

**Sample JSON object I get from the API depending on the payment status**

```
//When not paid
{
    status: 0,
    message: 'Not Paid',
    amount: 20
}

//When paid
{
    status: 1,
    message: 'Paid',
    amount: 20
}

//When cancelled
{
    status: 2,
    message: 'Cancelled',
    amount: 20
}
```

**AJAX code am using to post data to the controller**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Mpesa Payment code
$('.mpesa').on('click', function () {

    //Gets the MPESA type
    var type = $('.mpesa').prop('id');
    var quote = $('#quote').val();
    var phone = $('#phone').val();
    //Converts to a JSON object
    var type ={
      'type': type,
      'quote' : quote,
      'phone' : phone,
    };

    console.log(type);

    $.ajax({
        //Contains controller of payment
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'paymentFinal',
        data: JSON.stringify(type),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function success(response) {
            window.location.href="success" ;
        },
        error: function error(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
//End Payment API
```

**Laravel Controller am posting data to from above AJAX code**

```
 public
    function payFinal(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request->all());

         //Convert to a JSON object the request 
        $data =(object)$request->all();

        //Session get of some data fetched from another controller
        $quote = $request->session()->get('quoteID');

        //Store all the data in an array
         $all = array(
            'phone' => $data->phone,
            'quote_id' => $quote,
            'payment_type' => $data->type,
        );

        //Posts data to Payment Checkout using curl
        $response = $this->global_Curl($all, 'api/payment/checkout');
        //dd($response);

        //Get checkoutresponseId from response
        $checkID = $response->data->CheckoutRequestID;

        //Payment type
        $type = $data->type;

        $data = array(
            'payment_reference' => $checkID,
            'payment_type' => $type
        );

        //1st call to the Payment API before sleep
        $paySt = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/payment/status')->data;

        sleep(15);

        //Second call to the API after sleep to check if status has changed
        $payStat = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/payment/status')->data;

        if($payStat->status == '1'){
            return 'true';   
        }
    }
```

**New AJAX code am using**

```
$('.mpesa').on('click', function () {
    setInterval(function() {
       alert('clicked');
      //Gets the MPESA type
       var type = $('.mpesa').prop('id');
      var quote = $('#quote').val();
      var phone = $('#phone').val();
      //Converts to a JSON object
      var type ={
        'type': type,
        'quote' : quote,
        'phone' : phone,
      };

    console.log(type);
    $.ajax({
        //Contains controller of payment
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'paymentFinal',
        data: JSON.stringify(type),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function success(response) {
          if(response) {
              window.location.href="success";
          }
        },
        error: function error(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}, 15000); // Execute every 15 seconds
});
```

Comment: You could always use AJAX to poll an endpoint in the background, which checks the result of the payment. Have it do it every 5 seconds, with a loading indicator on the front end. When payment is confirmed redirect the user.

Comment: You don't typically want to delay any PHP invocation. Simply repeat the request to the same PHP script until it succeeds. E.g. have a self-refreshing website, or an AJAX driven site that contacts the server which contacts the gateway ever so often.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the help,, would you mind describing me using an example,, I have absolutely no idea of how to handle the task in AJAX,, when posting data to the controller am using AJAX but I have no idea how to refresh the page using the same AJAX code and repeat the request of the same PHP script..

Comment: @fubar Thanks for the help,, kindly explain to me using an example of AJAX request...

Comment: @deceze Kindly check the question,, I have added the AJAX code am using

Comment: @fubar Kindly check updated question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so lets break your problem down. First of all, you want to delay your AJAX code to execute every 15 seconds. For this, you wrap your AJAX in a `setInterval()` javascript method. So it should end up looking like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        //Contains controller of payment
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'paymentFinal',
        data: JSON.stringify(type),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function success(response) {
            window.location.href="success" ;
        },
        error: function error(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}, 15000); // Execute every 15 seconds
```

Next, you want to do something based on the status that your code returns. For this, you need to change the success case of your AJAX method to something like this:

```
    success: function success(response) {
        if(response) {
            window.location.href="success"
        }
    }
```

That's it for the javascript side. For the PHP side, you can remove this because you are now handling the interval on the frontend:

```
    sleep(15);

    //Second call to the API after sleep to check if status has changed
    $payStat = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/payment/status')->data;
```

And also change the return type from a string to a boolean:

```
if($payStat->status == 1){
        return response()->json(true);   // Sends back a JSON response to your AJAX
    }
```

And that should do what you want it to do.

Now, a few suggestions on your code:

- You might want to make provisions for more cases than just the
  success AJAX case
- Make sure you disable the button when the user
  clicks the payment button, or else every time they press it it will
  start a new 15 second interval
- Try wrapping your PHP code in a try-catch block to allow for graceful error handling
- Make provisions for more than just the success case

Comment: ,, Thanks alot .. the code works fine  but I am experiencing 2 minor bugs,, the **first one** is according to your code you are using setInterval() method,, when the user clicks on the payment it is waiting for 15 seconds before posting the data,, I want it to post instantly on the 1st time and wait for 15 seconds for subsequent time,, **secondly** I have tried to dd() the data being passed from AJAX but it is not being passed from the AJAX code

Comment: @Patweb I can not disagree more with this answer; you need to use queues for this; any sleep (in any kind of language) is a huge code-smell. DO NOT DO THIS.

Comment: @Kyslik I am answering the question, I am not endorsing the method

Comment: @Patweb Put the contents of `setInterval` inside of a function and call it once before `setInterval` starts and also put it inside of the `setInterval` method

Answer (score 0):

use this
sleep(5);
in laravel controller

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).